# SSL and Oracle HTTP server (OHS)

Tags: oracle11g

Welcome.

There is centos 5.5, oracle 11g release 1, Oracle Application Server 10g Release 3 (10.1.3.2.0) for Linux x86.

creating a wallet by owm and openssl ... finally getting ready to use wallet.

more interested with what settings to change in the configuration OHS to make it work?

changing the way in ssl.conf in place of default set the path to the next folder, where lies the wallet
start opmnctl - does not work in the logs I see error

[Thu Dec 09 16:22:45 2010] [error] Server virt11gr1: 443: can't open an encrypted
wallet file: / opt/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/ohs/ohs/conf/ssl.wlt/mywallet when opm
n is usingPlease enable it as SSO wallet

in opmn.xml also found a string of wallet prescribe the path there - will not start ... (
guys, tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your wallet via OWM and set the checkbox Auto Login

Answer (score 2):

If we use through ORAPKI, then :

```
# Create root wallet (for example, CA wallet)
./orapki wallet create -wallet ./root -auto_login_only

# Add a self-signed certificate (CA certificate) to the root wallet
./orapki wallet add -wallet ./root -dn 'CN=your-host.com,C=IN' -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 3650 -auto_login_only

# Export self-signed certificate from the wallet
./orapki wallet export -wallet ./root -dn 'CN=your-host.com,C=IN' -cert ./root/b64certificate.txt

# Create a user wallet (for example, a customer wallet)
./orapki wallet create -wallet ./user -auto_login_only

# Add a certificate request
./orapki wallet add -wallet ./user -dn 'CN=your-host.com,C=IN' -keysize 1024 -auto_login_only

# Export the certificate request
./orapki wallet export -wallet ./user -dn 'CN=your-host.com,C=IN' -request ./user/creq.txt

# Create a certificate (issued by CA)
./orapki cert create -wallet ./root -request ./user/creq.txt -cert ./user/cert.txt -validity 3650

# Add a trusted certificate (CA certificate) to the wallet
./orapki wallet add -wallet ./user -trusted_cert -cert ./root/b64certificate.txt -auto_login_only

# Add a user certificate
./orapki wallet add -wallet ./user -user_cert -cert ./user/cert.txt -auto_login_only

# Display contents of wallet
./orapki wallet display -wallet ./root
```